# Utilise AWS IoT on non-supported hardware

Tags: amazon-web-services, linux, node.js

Before I dig in too far, is there any way I can use any of the AWS IoT core functions on non-supported hardware?

I can use the AWS Node.js libraries that are available (for my hardware), but I don't think this is getting me into the core services.

My alternative is just to build my own ecosystem on existing services like IAM/S3/SNS/EC2.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else would like to benefit from my experience, the answer is "kind of".

Without a Greengrass kernel, you will not get many of the core features and benefits, but you can use JS/Node SDK to start migrating to AWS IoT.

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js

For me, the problem was that my ARM device has an armv61, and Greengrass requires a minimum armv71, which is frustrating for an ecosystem designed for very low power devices.

But, at least I can base some of my back-end on the presumption that we will eventually move to updated hardware.